# Google sheets Query function with Arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

For each of the email id, I want to get latest 10 records by timestamp. How do I get the results with `arrayformula?` Query function is not important as long as I can still achieve this with arrayformula. Here is the sample data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YAHA02VM-5MXzVKhkxu_eODPKObpoz441mGX8lOFu5M/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second thoughts, maybe this is bit cheeky, but this might do it ( taken from [conditional rank idea](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2017/03/09/excel-rank-formula-example/) )

```
=ArrayFormula(filter(A2:C,countifs(A2:A,">="&A2:A,B2:B,B2:B)<=10,A2:A<>""))
```

[image]

EDIT

The above assumes (because the data is time-stamped) dups shouldn't occur. If they do and the data is pre-sorted, you can use row number as a proxy for time stamp as suggested by @Aresvik.

Alternatively, you could count separately

(a) only rows with a later timestamp

plus

(b) rows with the same time stamp but with earlier (or identical) row number

```
=ArrayFormula(filter(A2:C,countifs(A2:A,">"&A2:A,B2:B,B2:B)+countifs(A2:A,"="&A2:A,B2:B,B2:B,row(A2:A),"<="&row(A2:A))<=10,A2:A<>""))
```

Comment: Excellent solution. Unlikely, but if the values in A are not all unique, then you could use `row()`, and just reference `B`. -->  `countifs(row(B2:B),">="&row(B2:B),B2:B,B2:B)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this on another sheet, row 1:

```
=arrayformula(query({query({Sheet1!$A:$C},"order by Col1 desc,Col2",1),{"Dupe position";countifs(query({Sheet1!$A2:$C},"select Col2 order by Col1 desc,Col2",0),query({Sheet1!$A2:$C},"select Col2 order by Col1 desc,Col2",0),row(Sheet1!$A2:$C),"<="&row(Sheet1!$A2:$C))}},"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col1 is not null and Col4 <= 10 order by Col1",1))
```

[image]

You can adjust the number of records found by adjusting `Col4 <= 10`, and also the final sort by altering `order by Col1` at the end of the formula.

**Explanation**

This gets the data from Sheet1, sorts it by date desc then email asc:
`query({Sheet1!$A:$C},"order by Col1 desc,Col2",1)`

[image]

Then to the side of this data, a `COUNTIFS()` is used to get the number each time an email appears in the list above (since it's sorted desc, 1 represents the most recent instance).

`countifs(<EmailColumnData>,<EmailColumnData>,row(<EmailColumn>),"<="&row(<EmailColumn>))`

[image]

[image]

In place of `<EmailColumnData>` in the `COUNTIF()` is:
`query({Sheet1!$A2:$C},"select Col2 order by Col1 desc,Col2",0)`

[image]

In place of `<EmailColumn>` above, we only want the row number so we don't need the actual data. We can use:
`Sheet1!$A2:$C`

Various `{}` work as arrays to bring the data together.

Eg., `{a,b,c;d,e,f}` would result in three columns, with `a, b, c` in row 1 and `d, e, f` in row 2. `,` is a new column, `;` is a return for a new row.

A final query around everything gets the 3 columns we need, where the count number in col 4 is <=10, then sorts the output by Col1 (date asc).

Comment: Thankyou, this does the job but quite complicated to follow

Comment: I've added an explanation. Also added additional 'helper' columns in your sheet on the 'Aresvik solution' tab so you can see what's going on. The formulas in the 3 yellow cells are combined in the green cell.

Comment: This a neat solution to a tricky problem and probably about as simple as it gets.

Comment: Thanks. My gut feeling is that there is probably a simpler way, but ultimately I can't see any other option than counting instances of each email.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a new sheet ("Erik Help") with the following formula in A1:

`=ArrayFormula({"Submitted Time","Email","Score";SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(IF(Sheet1!B2:B=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!B2:B<>""))),Sheet1!A2:A&"|"&Sheet1!B2:B&"|"&Sheet1!C2:C,),,COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A)))," ",0,1)),SEQUENCE(MAX(COUNTIF(Sheet1!B2:B,Sheet1!B2:B))),0),"LIMIT 10")),"|",1,0),1,0)})`

The number of records is set after `LIMIT`.

The order is set by the final two numbers: `1,0` (meaning "sort by column 1 in reverse order," which, as currently set, is sorting in reverse order by date/time).

Comment: Thank you Erik! This does the job . Unfortunately, its quite complicated to follow

Comment: Do keep in mind that this forum (as well as any other forum like it) is run entirely by volunteers in our free time. Forums are designed to offer a little knowledge or a "nudge in the right direction" to many people. Most often, creating a solution for a forum takes only a few minutes and explaining is fairly straightforward. In this case, creating the solution took quite a bit more time than is typical; and explaining in detail would take even more. It seems Aresvik did choose to put in that extra time for you; but my own regular paying client load is too heavy for me to do so at this time.

Comment: understand and appreciate your contribution